# UIImage not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, segue

When I segue my `UIImageView` from my `NewsTableViewController.swift`, the image does not appear in my `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`.

Here is an image of my simulator:

[image: Simulator image[1]]

---

Here is an image of my `Main.storyboard`:

[image: Main.storyboard image[2]]

---

Here is my `prepareForSegue()` method code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailTableViewController
            destinationController.item = items[indexPath.row]
            let newsImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row]))
            destinationController.image = newsImage
        }
    }
}
```

It is also worth mentioning that my image in my `NewsTableViewController.swift` is set to 0x0, and in my `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`, it is set to 600x216. I don't know if this would matter or not. If you desire any code, please do feel free to ask.

FYI, I use Swift.

Comment: You mean your **`imageView`** in `NewsTableViewController` is set to 0x0 ?

Comment: You are passing the image view to the NewsDetailTableViewController, is that on purpose? It looks like you already have an UIImageView created in the interface builder. Try passing just the image to the NewsDetailTableViewController and simply set the image on the UIImageView when the NewsDetailTableViewController loads.

Comment: @AlanPerez I don't understand. You can add an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

In prepareForSegue the IBOutlets of your destinationController have not been initialized yet. Just pass detailImages to another array property on NewsDetailTableViewController. Change your prepareForSegue to:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailTableViewController
            destinationController.item = items[indexPath.row]
            destinationController.imageNames = detailImages
        }
    }
}
```

Then in NewsTableViewController add the following code:

```
 var imageNames:[String]?

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //replace with whatever identifier you're using
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = self.imageNames[indexPath.row]?

    return cell
}
```

Comment: How do I pass the image array thats in the main view controller?

Comment: I assume `detailImages[indexPath.row]` is an array of strings. You can create a [String] property on NewsDetailTableViewController and set it in prepareForSegue e.g.(`destinationController.imageNames = detailImages`)

Comment: I added this, but the line of code in the `viewDidLoad()` has an error saying: > Value of type 'NewsTableViewController.swift' has no member 'image'.

Comment: How does `destinationController.image = newsImage` work in your code then? Is destinationController not of type NewsDetailTableViewController?

Comment: There is no error in that line, but is just doesn't fix it. The `destinationController` has this line of code acquainted with it `let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailTableViewController`.

Comment: Yes, my point is how are you able to set a property named "image" on a NewsDetailTableViewController in one place, but in another the compiler is saying there is no such property. In viewDidLoad all you want to do is set NewsDetailTableViewController image view's image to the image you passed in. But it seems like your image view is in a tableview cell, so you probably need to actually set in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Yes, my image is set in a table view cell. What line of code shall I add? I find it quite confusing.

Comment: My image view array in `NewsTableViewController.swift` is called detailImages.

Comment: I updated my answer, but you are still making no sense. And what you are asking for the comments in different from your original question. detailImage is not an array of image views or this line `let newsImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row]))` would make no sense.

Comment: When I add the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` line and the `var imageNames:[String]?` line, there is an error saying "Type [String]? has no subscript members"